# tensorflow GradientDescentOptimizer function trains the paramter layer by layer?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Does tensorflow's GradientDescentOptimizer trains the internal network layer by layer or just use a regular method like Back propagation. How deep the network could be for GradientDescentOptimizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just uses standard back prop, not layer by layer.

The network could be theoretically as deep as you can hold in memory. But the deeper it gets the longer it will take to train and the less useful successive layers will be. At a certain point extra layers can even start to increase the error on training data.

Comment: If that is only standard back prop, why now we can get much better result than 10 years ago? It feels strange.

Comment: As I understand it, bigger nets, better data, better computational power, But this kind of question is outside the scope of SO